# Reproducing index of notation

Tags: glossaries, indexing

I am trying to find a package or a way to reproduce the following index of notation  to make one similar to it. The AMS template is very different and has page numbers and other questions seem to have drastically different indices

Feel free to change the tags I couldn't find anything more relevant

[image: The index]

Comment: The `glossaries` package might be interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the package `nomencl`. Here is a little example of use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[stdsubgroups,nocfg]{nomencl}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Index of Notation}
\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{A}}{%
      \item[\textbf{Analysis}]}{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{K}}{%
        \item[\textbf{Sets}]}{%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{P}}{%
          \item[\textbf{Probability/measure theory}]}{%
            \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{X}}{%
            \item[\textbf{Spaces of functions}]}{%
              {}}}}}}
\usepackage{setspace}
    \makenomenclature
\begin{document}

    \nomenclature[ainf]{$\inf \varnothing$}{$\inf \varnothing=+\infty$}%
    \nomenclature[aint]{$\lfloor x \rfloor$}{integer part of $x$}%
    \nomenclature[at]{$x^\top$}{transpose of the vector $x$}%
    \nomenclature[ka]{$A^c$}{complement of the set $A$}%
    \nomenclature[kint]{int $A$}{interior of the set $A$}%
    \nomenclature[kcl]{cl $A$}{closure of the set $A$}%
    \nomenclature[pd]{$\sim$}{distributed as}%
    \nomenclature[pDir]{$\delta_x$}{Dirac measure at $x$}%
    \nomenclature[xcm]{$C(M)$}{space of continuous functions\\$f\colon M \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$}%
\onehalfspacing
\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

See the manual for the usage, in particular section **2.9.1 Advanced subgroups** (but there seems be a typo in the example of the manual of the latest version, 5.2, because `{R}` and `{G}` must be replaced by `{V}` and `{C}` respectively.)

This above example give:
[image]

Comment: How do I make them two columns